# Improve performance of Graphql (graphene-django) for 4 levels of nested lists

Tags: django, graphql, nested-lists, graphene-django

I am using Django 4 with graphene-Django 3 and I need to structure a response that must be 4 levels of lists and the bottom level a dictionary. Here the implementation

```
class FailureSensorType(DjangoObjectType):
      class Meta:
         model = FailureSensor
      spectra = graphene.Field(SpectraGraphType)
      ...
      rest of fields


class SpectraGraphType(graphene.ObjectType):
   name = graphene.List(graphene.String)
   spectra_z = graphene.List(graphene.List(graphene.List(SpectraZGraphType)))


class SpectraZGraphType(graphene.ObjectType):
   _id = graphene.String(required=False)
   collection_name = graphene.String(required=False)
   values = graphene.List(graphene.Float, required=False)
   values_names = graphene.List(graphene.Int, required=False)
   sidebands = graphene.List(graphene.Float, required=False)
   rpm_detected = graphene.Int(required=False)
   anomaly = graphene.Int()


def resolve_spectra(self, info):
        if self.anomaly_type == "spectra":
            spectra_name = set()
            for graph_y in self.get_map_Y():
                spectra_name.add(str(self.id) + '-' + graph_y.split()[-1])

            spectra_z_list = list()
            spectra_z_list_new = list()
            for i, x in enumerate(np.split(self.get_map_Z(), id_z)):
                spectra_z_list.append(x.tolist())


            for spectra_z in spectra_z_list:
                zero_index_list = list()
                for index_obj, graph_z_obj in enumerate(spectra_z):
                    zero_index = list()
                    for i, graph_z_value in enumerate(graph_z_obj):
                        if graph_z_value != '{"anomaly": 0}':
                            zero_index.append(i)

                    zero_index_list.append(zero_index)

                new_z_list = list() 
                for z_obj in spectra_z:
                    new_z = [v for i, v in enumerate(z_obj) if i in zero_index_set]
                    z_dict_list = list()
                    for dict_string in new_z:
                        r = json.loads(dict_string.replace("|", ",").replace("(", "[").replace(")", "]"))
                        if "_id" not in r:
                            r["_id"] = ""
                        if "collection_name" not in r:
                            r["collection_name"] = ""    
                        if "rpm_detected" not in r:
                            r["rpm_detected"] = -1    
                        if "values" in r:
                            r["values"] = json.loads(r["values"])
                        else:
                            r["values"] = []
                        if "values_names" in r:
                            r["values_names"] = json.loads(r["values_names"])
                        else:
                            r["values_names"] = []
                        if "sidebands" in r:
                            r["sidebands"] = json.loads(r["sidebands"])
                        else:
                            r["sidebands"] = []
                        z_dict_list.append(r)
                    new_z_list.append(z_dict_list)

                spectra_z_list_new.append(new_z_list)
                
            return {
                "name": spectra_name,
                "spectra_z": spectra_z_list_new
            }
```

This is the graphql query:

```
inspectSensorFailureBySystem(){
 failureSensors{
  anomalyType
  failureSensors{
    spectra{
      name
      spectraZ {
        Id
        collectionName
        rpmDetected
        anomaly
        values
        valuesNames
        sidebands
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result of this query is:

```
{
 "data": {
   "inspectSensorFailureBySystem": [
     {
       "failureSensors": [
         {
        "anomalyType": "spectra",
        "failureSensors": [
          {
            "spectra": {
              "name": [
                "15339-envelope_spectra",
                "15339-envelope_spectra_timedomain",
                "15339-spectra_timedomain",
                "15339-spectra"
              ],
              "spectraZ": [
                [
                  [
                    {
                      "Id": "628bd17db4aff3060810a726",
                      "collectionName": "spectrum",
                      "rpmDetected": -1,
                      "anomaly": -1,
                      "values": [],
                      "valuesNames": [],
                      "sidebands": []
                    },
                    ...
                    {
                      "Id": "62e8d3119aa606584e88b228",
                      "collectionName": "timedomain",
                      "rpmDetected": 1256,
                      "anomaly": 1,
                      "values": [
                        261.1224,
                        522.2448,
                        783.3672,
                        1044.4896,
                        1305.612,
                        1566.7344,
                        1827.8568,
                        2088.9792,
                        2872.3464,
                        3133.4688
                      ],
                      "valuesNames": [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3,
                        4,
                        5,
                        6,
                        7,
                        8,
                        11,
                        12
                      ],
                      "sidebands": []
                        }
                      ]
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The data comes directly from a stringified list of dictionaries (spectra_z) which is parsed in the previous resolver and it works pretty fast (less than 0.2s). So, retrieving data from the database and then parsing from string to the desired nested lists and final dictionaries is really fast.

But after the resolver is finished and I pass the result to GraphGL engine, GraphGL takes more than 30s to parse the given result and send the final response.

On the other hand, if I just get the stringified values from database  (spectra_z) and just pass them as string (no nested lists involved), obviously GraphGL response is super fast.

I am not an expert in GraphGL and I would like to know how could I speed up graphene-Django to parse this response faster (since 30 seconds to get the response is not acceptable).
Does Exist any kind of setting parameters to speed it up or any trick?

---

### **EDITED**

I followed the advice from @MichelFloyd, so the structure now is like this:

```
class FailureSensorType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = FailureSensor
    spectra = graphene.Field(SpectraGraphType)

    def resolve_spectra(self, info): <-- CHANGED
        return SpectraGraphType(id=self.id)

class SpectraGraphType(graphene.ObjectType): <-- CHANGED
id = graphene.Int()
name = graphene.List(graphene.String)
spectra_z = graphene.List(graphene.List(graphene.List(SpectraZGraphType)))


def resolve_name(self, info, **kwargs):
    self = FailureSensor.objects.get(id=self.id)
    if self.anomaly_type == "spectra":
        spectra_name = set()
        for graph_y in self.get_map_Y():
            spectra_name.add(str(self.id) + '-' + graph_y.split()[-1])
    return spectra_name


def resolve_spectra_z(self, info):
    self = FailureSensor.objects.get(id=self.id)
    if self.anomaly_type == "spectra":
        sections = 4
        z_len = len(self.get_map_Z()) // sections

        id_z = list(range(z_len, z_len * (sections + 1), z_len))[:-1]

        spectra_z_list = list()
        spectra_z_list_new = list()
        for i, x in enumerate(np.split(self.get_map_Z(), id_z)):
            spectra_z_list.append(x.tolist())


        for spectra_z in spectra_z_list:
            zero_index_list = list()
            for index_obj, graph_z_obj in enumerate(spectra_z):
                zero_index = list()
                for i, graph_z_value in enumerate(graph_z_obj):
                    if graph_z_value != '{"anomaly": 0}':
                        zero_index.append(i)

                zero_index_list.append(zero_index)

            zero_index_set = set()
            for zero_index in zero_index_list:
                for zero in zero_index:
                    zero_index_set.add(zero)

            new_z_list = list() 
            for z_obj in spectra_z:
                new_z = [v for i, v in enumerate(z_obj) if i in zero_index_set]
                z_dict_list = list()
                for dict_string in new_z:
                    z_dict_list.append(SpectraZGraphType(text=dict_string)) <--- UPDATED TO PASS LIST OF STRINGIFIED VALUES
                new_z_list.append(z_dict_list)
                #new_z_list.append(new_z)

            spectra_z_list_new.append(new_z_list)
            
        return spectra_z_list_new

    return None
```

new resolvers for the bottom level:

```
class SpectraZGraphType(graphene.ObjectType):
    text = graphene.String(required=False)
    _id = graphene.String(required=False)
    collection_name = graphene.String(required=False)
    values = graphene.List(graphene.Float, required=False)
    values_names = graphene.List(graphene.Int, required=False)
    sidebands = graphene.List(graphene.Float, required=False)
    rpm_detected = graphene.Int(required=False)
    anomaly = graphene.Int()

def resolve__id(self, info):
    r = json.loads(self.text.replace("|", ",").replace("(", "[").replace(")", "]"))
    if "_id" not in r:
        r["_id"] = ""
    return r["_id"]
def resolve_collection_name(self, info):
    r = json.loads(self.text.replace("|", ",").replace("(", "[").replace(")", "]"))
    if "collection_name" not in r:
        r["collection_name"] = ""    
    return r["collection_name"]

def resolve_rpm_detected(self, info):
    r = json.loads(self.text.replace("|", ",").replace("(", "[").replace(")", "]"))
    if "rpm_detected" not in r:
        r["rpm_detected"] = -1    
    return r["rpm_detected"]

def resolve_values(self, info):
    r = json.loads(self.text.replace("|", ",").replace("(", "[").replace(")", "]"))
   
    if "values" in r:
        r["values"] = json.loads(r["values"])
    else:
        r["values"] = []
    return r["values"]

def resolve_values_names(self, info):
    r = json.loads(self.text.replace("|", ",").replace("(", "[").replace(")", "]"))
    if "values_names" in r:
        r["values_names"] = json.loads(r["values_names"])
    else:
        r["values_names"] = []
    return r["values_names"]

def resolve_sidebands(self, info):
    r = json.loads(self.text.replace("|", ",").replace("(", "[").replace(")", "]"))
    if "sidebands" in r:
        r["sidebands"] = json.loads(r["sidebands"])
    else:
        r["sidebands"] = []

    return r["sidebands"]

def resolve_anomaly(self, info):
    r = json.loads(self.text.replace("|", ",").replace("(", "[").replace(")", "]"))

    return r["anomaly"]
```

It still is taking around 30 seconds to load. I am not sure if The resolver_spectra_z is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

1. Define a resolver for spectra that just returns the name array
2. Define a resolver for spectraZ that just returns the spectraZ list
3. Define individual resolvers for all the fields in the spectraZ object. This would avoid that long series of `if` statements where you are essentially resolving one field per pass through the keys
4. Let GraphQL marshal all the results together into the return object

This would have the added benefit of not over-computing all the nested fields if not all of them are requested by the client. As it is even if you just wanted the names everything else would get computed as well.

Comment: I have tried with your idea, but the performance is the same, around 30 seconds to load. I have edited the question with your idea but I am not sure if The resolver_spectra_z is ok. What do you think?

Comment: Anyway to get rid of all those `json.loads()` in each individual resolver? Do it one level higher and attach it to the parent before the field resolvers fire? Also just looks like a lot of transformation in `resolve_spectra_z`

Comment: I edited again the question and this is the result:
It still is taking around 30 seconds to load. I can see that resolving the resolve_spectra_z es really fast, less than 0.2 seconds, but I print the resolve__id and I can see that it is called sequentially one by one, and here is the bottleneck ( have more than 600 different SpectraGraphType). Is it possible somehow to fire all (or a bunch of) the bottom resolvers in parallel?